Ubuntu Server disk cloning + saving on another disk in network
This my first question here and bear with me if some info is missing.
So, i have this technical problem:
I have a Ubuntu Server installed on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B ( so on ARM ) and i need to do a full backup and upload it on another PC in the same local network ( A Windows PC ).
This is the server FS:

| Filesystem    | Size | Used | Avail | Use% | Mounted on      |
|---------------|------|------|-------|------|-----------------|
| tmpfs         | 375M | 6.4M | 368M  | 2%   | /run            |
| /dev/sda2     | 110G | 38G  | 69G   | 36%  | /               |
| tmpfs         | 1.9G | 0    | 1.9G  | 0%   | /dev/shm        |
| tmpfs         | 5.0M | 12K  | 5.0M  | 1%   | /run/lock       |
| /dev/sda1     | 253M | 138M | 115M  | 55%  | /boot/firmware  |
| tmpfs         | 375M | 4.0K | 375M  | 1%   | /run/user/1000  |
| total         | 113G | 38G  | 71G   | 35%  | -               |




I thought of maybe set up a fileshare ( like SAMBA ) on my windows machine and putting the backup there.
I never did Linux backups and i don't know how to make one, so some questions:

What is the best way of creating a backup?
I need to backup sda1 and sda2 ?
Best way to port it on another machine with different OS ?
Once i have the backup in hand, with a pristine new SSD, how i import it onto it?

Feel free to ask me if you need further info,
thanks in advance!


What is the best way of creating a backup?

While this site doesn't recommend software, I'm adding the following link due to it being pretty much the de facto standard for Linux image cloning and backup:



Clonezilla: The Free and Open Source Software for Disk Imaging and Cloning - x32/x64.
Here's the version for ARM: Clonezilla for ARM.

I need to backup sda1 and sda2...

Specifically, the OP needs to download the LiveCD/USB version as the opening page states:


Clonezilla live is suitable for single machine backup and restore.


Best way to port it on another machine with different OS ?

Don't worry about porting it.  Save the exact cloned partition layout as a file somewhere on the LAN.


Once i have the backup in hand, with a pristine new SSD, how i import it onto it?

I don't quite now how to do this on a Pi, but in some cases Clonezilla can do a disk to disk copy of partitions, much like GParted, but if question 3 cannot be skipped due to the fact that the Pi cannot contain multiple SDCards/SSD's, you would do the reverse of Question 3 and restore the saved image back on to the new SSD.  Be aware that new UUID's may be needed once the image is transferred to the new SSD.




Hi, i tried installing 'clonezilla' and on the windows machine i have a Share there ready. but i recieve this error when executing the process, i need to work on live partitions, is this not possible ? the error is:  Error! No existing disk(s) or no unmounted disk(s) are found! To use Clonezilla to save or clone a disk, the source disk must exist or be unmounted! If you are sure the disk exists in this machine, maybe the kernel is too old?
Press "Enter" to exit...

You can't install Clonezilla.  Create a Live CD/USB, or in the Pi's Case Burn the ARM image linked above to an SD Card then boot from the SD Card.  Once booted, create an image and save it to your share location

Watch this video

Perfect!Thanks! ill try and i will let you know

BACKUP:

Assuming you have the free space or an external thumb drive plugged in, you can recreate an image file of the rpi disk and output that to an *.img.gz file.


    sudo apt-get install gzip -y
    mkdir -p ~/backup
    sudo dd if=/dev/sda | gzip > ~/backup/rpi_backup_$(date +%F).img.gz

RESTORE/RECOVER:

From any PC Uncompress the gz file
Download/Run an image-burning software such as Rufus.
Place your new microsd into said computer
Use Rufus to write the image to the microSD card:
Select your microSD card under “Device”.
Choose the decompressed img file under “Boot selection”.
Click “START” and confirm.
Insert the microSD card into your Raspberry Pi and power it on.

